# npm swiper in vuejs, my swiper can't do the autoplay feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, swiper.js

i've used the code autoplay in css swipe npm, but it can't play the autoplay

```
initSwiper() {
      this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        speed: 500,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        
        autoplay: {
          delay: 1000,
        },
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
      });
    },
```

this is what my code is, from the tutorial it is already exactly what needed to use the autoplay, but the autoplay seems doesnt work. can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: what does this have to do with `node.js` and `npm` and `vue.js`?

Comment: may be a stupid question, but do you actually call `initSwiper`?